# Drill through bar chart Dash plotly

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I was trying to create a bar chart where i want to drill through district and then see the population of various cities for 3 year ranges.
Basically i found this 
https://community.plotly.com/t/drill-down-function-for-graphs-embedded-in-dash-app/12290/9
but i am unable to implement

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from dash.dependencies import Output, Input, State
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
from pandas import read_excel

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

# app = dash.Dash()
file_name = 'samplePop1.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(file_name)
print(df.head())

colors = {
    'black' : '#000000',
    'text' :  '#696969',
    'plot_color' : '#C0C0C0',
    'white' : '#FFFFF'
}


app.layout = html.Div ([
                        dcc.Graph(    
                            id = 'bar-chart',
                        figure = { 'data' : 
                                    [
                                        {'x' : df['Name'],'y':df['Population Census 1991'],'type':'bar','name':'Population Census 1991'},
                                        {'x' : df['Name'],'y':df['Population Census 2001'],'type':'bar','name':'Population Census 2001'},
                                        {'x' : df['Name'],'y':df['Population Census 2011'],'type':'bar','name':'Population Census 2011'}

                                    ],
                                'layout' : {
                                    'plot_bgcolor' : colors['white'],
                                    'paper_bgcolor' : colors['white'],
                                    'font' : {
                                        'color' : colors['white']
                                    },
                                    'title' : 'Bar Chart',
                                    'orientation':'h'
                                }
                                }
                        )
                    ])
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(port =  '8080' , debug ='True')
```

the bar chart should show population district wise first for 3 year range and when i click on a district
it shall show district wise comparison.
also another basic chart where their will be 2 click action district wise and city wise to show population for 3 year ranges it should show values clearly more likely it should be scroll-able.

link to the csv file 
https://github.com/9192gks/mapbox/blob/master/samplePop1.csv

Answer (score 2):

Checkout this example of Drill Down in Dash with the help of callback_context.
[image]

In this example I am showcasing just a single level drill down to keep it simple but with few modifications multi -level drill down can be achieved.
There’s a back button for going back to the original figure. The back button is shown only on the level two of the drill down and hides on the original bottom level.

Code:

```py
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])

# creating a dummy sales dataframe
product_sales = {'vendors':['VANS','VANS','VANS','VANS','NIKE','NIKE','NIKE','ADIDAS','ADIDAS','CONVERSE','CONVERSE','CONVERSE'],
                 'products': ['Tshirts','Sneakers','Caps','Clothing','Sports Outfit','Sneakers','Caps','Accessories','Bags','Sneakers','Accessories','Tshirts'],
                 'units sold': [2,15,3,8,37,13,7,4,12,7,8,2]
                 }
product_sales_df = pd.DataFrame(product_sales)

# all vendors sales pie chart
def sales_pie():
    df = product_sales_df.groupby('vendors').sum().reset_index()
    fig = px.pie(df, names='vendors',
                 values='units sold', hole=0.4)
    fig.update_layout(template='presentation', title='Sales distribution per Vendor')
    return fig

# creating app layout
app.layout = dbc.Container([
    dbc.Card([
            dbc.Button('', id='back-button', outline=True, size="sm",
                        className='mt-2 ml-2 col-1', style={'display': 'none'}),
            dbc.Row(
                dcc.Graph(
                        id='graph',
                        figure=sales_pie()
                    ), justify='center'
            )
    ], className='mt-3')
])

#Callback
@app.callback(
    Output('graph', 'figure'),
    Output('back-button', 'style'), #to hide/unhide the back button
    Input('graph', 'clickData'),    #for getting the vendor name from graph
    Input('back-button', 'n_clicks')
)
def drilldown(click_data,n_clicks):

    # using callback context to check which input was fired
    ctx = dash.callback_context
    trigger_id = ctx.triggered[0]["prop_id"].split(".")[0]

    if trigger_id == 'graph':

        # get vendor name from clickData
        if click_data is not None:
            vendor = click_data['points'][0]['label']

            if vendor in product_sales_df.vendors.unique():
                # creating df for clicked vendor
                vendor_sales_df = product_sales_df[product_sales_df['vendors'] == vendor]

                # generating product sales bar graph
                fig = px.bar(vendor_sales_df, x='products',
                             y='units sold', color='products')
                fig.update_layout(title='<b>{} product sales<b>'.format(vendor),
                                  showlegend=False, template='presentation')
                return fig, {'display':'block'}     #returning the fig and unhiding the back button

            else:
                return sales_pie(), {'display': 'none'}     #hiding the back button

    else:
        return sales_pie(), {'display':'none'}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Also check out this [thread](https://community.plotly.com/t/show-and-tell-drill-down-functionality-in-dash-using-callback-context/54403?u=atharvakatre) for more info.