# How to create drill down operation for various chart in Plotly Dash using Django project?

Tags: python, django, plotly, plotly-dash

I have some basic knowledge of python and I am using a Django. I am trying to create drill down operation for various chart in Plotly Dash. I have tried multiple demos from online but I am not able to find any proper tutorials which provides. I have uploaded post in Plotly support, but don't gives a proper links or tutorials.

I was trying to this demo : [Drill through bar chart Dash plotly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61700316/drill-through-bar-chart-dash-plotly) , but this demo is in flask app but i need a code in Django. How do I put this code into Django?. Anyone please share useful demo links or some other tutorials with details which can I use. I need a code in Django project for drill down operation for various chart in Plotly Dash

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to integrate drill-down chart in django using plotly python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75371846/how-to-integrate-drill-down-chart-in-django-using-plotly-python)

Comment: I already responded to your last question. Why does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75286097/18018869) not help you? Tell me and I'll guide you.